# How to manually add a value to data source with combo box in Power Apps

Tags: combobox, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

The items in my Combo Box are being fetched from my data source. But how do I allow the user to manually enter an option in my Combo Box?

This option should then be saved in my data source.

[image]

I've tried different approaches with no luck.